# Newly installed programs always appear with external drives in Finder

Tags: macos, install

Why do newly-installed programs always appear with external drives in Finder on my MacBook?

For example, I just installed Zotero and no problem opening it but I see it listed under my external USB in finder with the little eject icon on the side. I’m afraid if I push eject I’ll delete the program and lose my work.

Why do the newly-installed programs appear there?

Comment: To clarify, what you’re seeing is *not* the installed program. It’s the virtual disk image from which you install the program by copying it to your Applications folder.

Answer (score 13):

When you download an application, it often comes inside a "Disk image" (a .dmg file). This is a virtual volume, which appears just like other disks on your Desktop, once you've launched it.

You have to copy the application from there into your /Applications folder. (Disk images often contain an alias to your Applications folder, so you can easily drop the app onto the folder.
Or, if the image contains an installer app or package, you have to run the installer app.

Once you have done this, you can eject the disk image and trash the .dmg file. If you haven't copied the app or installed it, then you need to make sure this is done first.

Comment: Only just realized how old fashioned of an experience that actually is: You take a CD, mount it in a drive, and install the application from that drive.

Comment: It is so old-fashioned that this is one of the places where you'll see vestiges of the NextStep OS in modern Macs. There's a funny-looking X symbol in the window there somewhere, and it's a bit of NextStep UI in Mac.

Comment: The alternative would be newbies "installing" apps in their Downloads folder [by simply unzipping etc]. I'll take archaic over 'oops' any day ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just to further clarify, understand what is happening conceptually when you download and install a program in modern day macOS:

1. In the "old days", you would buy a program from a physical store which would consist of a box containing a DVD, CD, or floppy disk/diskette (in order from newest to oldest).  We call these memory devices `"physical storage media"`.
2. The `storage media` contained the `"installation files"` which were essentially a copy of the application, and scripts to copy the application files to your internal hard drive, and make any configuration changes as necessary.  We'd specifically call these `physical media` containing the `installation files`, `"[an] install disk[s]"`.
3. You would then *physically* insert the external, `physical storage media` - `the install disk` - into the computer.
4. You would then "install the application" from the `install disk` to your `internal hard drive`.
5. You would then, usually, eject the `install disk`, as, with the application now installed directly to your faster `internal hard drive`, you no longer had use for it.*

Nowadays, we are `emulating` several of those steps `virtually`:

1. Instead of buying a physical box containing a physical `install disk` from a physical store, you're downloading a `virtual disk` from a "virtual" "store" (the Internet).
2. On macOS, these `virtual disks` usually have the extension `*.dmg`.*  "Inside" of the `*.dmg` file, similar to how a `*.zip` file can contain several other files, are all of the application files and installation scripts (if necessary), just like the physical `install disks` of old.
3. When you double-click a downloaded `*.dmg` file, macOS automatically recognizes it (you can read more about "file associations") as a `virtual disk` and automatically "mounts" it as an "external" drive.  This is the same process that occurs when you insert a CD/DVD (if you still have a CD/DVD drive), or when connect an external USB drive (USB thumb drive, USB card reader, USB hard drive, etc.).  The only difference here is that it is happening "virtually".  You aren't *actually* inserting anything physically into the computer, but the computer is going through the same motions with the `*.dmg` - the `virtual disk` - *as if you were*.  That's why when you double-click the downloaded `*.dmg` file, it appears in your `Finder` window sidebar with a little eject icon option, *just like any other physical *external* drive you might connect*.  Even though the `*.dmg` file is *already on your* `internal hard drive`, macOS *treats the mounted* `*.dmg` file *as if it were a separate disk/drive*.
4. From here, the rest of the process is the same: your `virtual disk` is mounted, just as if you inserted a physical `install disk`.  Now you have to install the application to your `internal disk drive`.  On macOS, this is usually as simple as copying the application to your root `/Applications` folder.  Some applications, though, have an install program (or install script) that do this for you automatically, and potentially handle some more advanced configuration.
5. Once the program is installed from the `virtual disk`, you can then "eject" ("unmount") the disk, just as you would eject a physical `install disk` in the old days.  The downloaded `*.dmg` file will still exist in your `/Downloads` folder, it's just no longer "unzipped" and "mounted".  Once your application is installed, you no longer need the `*.dmg` file either, except for archival purposes, or if you someday need to reinstall that same program (and same version of that program) again in the future.  But, except for very rare circumstances involving paid or hard-to-find software, in this Internet era, you can almost always just downloaded the `*.dmg` again (or the latest version of the program).

* <sup>In the "old days" of limited and expensive `internal storage`, it was sometimes necessary to keep the original, physical, external application media in the computer to run the application or game or video.  "Installation" would only involve copying the core application files to the hard drive, but larger application resources would still be read from the external media.  This was done because, while `external media` is/was much slower, it was better than the alternative of using up all of the precious and expensive `internal storage`.  Nowadays, `internal storage` is so cheap and plentiful, that you almost never see this done anymore, although it is still somewhat common for video game consoles (which are just specialized, branded computers).  Also, then, and now, some applications and games can be run without installation, directly from external media.  We call these "portable" or "standalone" applications or versions of applications.  Many handheld, cartridge-based video game systems still work like this.  These exceptions are all tangential to the idea of understanding how most modern-day macOS applications are installed, but it might be useful to know that *there are almost always exceptions to everything*.</sup>

* <sup>There are other common `virtual disk` extensions and formats.  `*.dmg` is the most common and standard Mac format.  `*.iso` is probably more common, but is generally seen more in Windows or Linux.  `*.udf` is rarer these days, and other specialized formats like `*.vmdk` are beyond the scope of this answer.</sup>

Comment: Nice answer but isn't .iso actually an image of a CD not a virtual disk ie it is fixed size. Also I suspect .dmg is only seen on Macs

Comment: Even if it were a fixed size, wouldn't it still be a virtualized representation of a physical disk?  And I don't think it is a fixed size as I've seen `*.iso` used to represent CD, DVD, and DVD9 formats, at least.  And the `*.iso` file size is always indicative of the size of the disk contents: a 100MiB CD will create an (approx.) 100MiB `*.iso`.  It's true that `*.iso` is most often seen "representing" an optical disc image.